cascading delete using kopf.adopt()
Started using kopf pretty recently. its great!! also kind of new k8s in general...
I have a pretty simple scenario. Two crds, parent and child... parent is created first. the child is created sometime later, but not by the parent... is there a way for child object to get its self 'adopted/owned' by the parent instance using kopf.adopt() method.
it would greatly simplify or even eliminate my cascading delete code.
or is there way using k8s client to add an ownerReference to an existing custom objects metadata?
Thanks in advance...

The magic happens when the parent CRD is deleted.kubernetes automatically cascades the deletion to its owned child resources due to the established ownership reference.This eliminates the need for explicit cascading deletion code in your child CRD handler.

after a little bit of hacking i came up with bit of code:
merge_patch = {
    "metadata": {
        "ownerReferences": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "siccat.com/v1",
                "blockOwnerDeletion": True,
                "kind": "Parent",
                "name": parent_box.metadata.name,
                "uid": parent_box.metadata.uid
            }
        ]}
}
api.patch_namespaced_custom_object(namespace=namespace, name=name,
                                   group="siccat.com",
                                   version="v1",
                                   plural="children",
                                   body=merge_patch)

essentially performing a patch in the create event handler...
this enables a cascading delete...
wondering if there is a better way accomplish the same thing?
